# Rest service : issues to download multiple Zip files using : ResponseBuilder

Tags: java, spring, rest, zip

I implemented a Rest Service to donwload files from a directory.

**There is my rest service : No problem here **

```
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response downloadZippedFile() {

        File file = new 
File("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111513.zip");
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
filename=\"MyJerseyZipFile.zip\"");
        return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

**Résult ==>** I can download 201707111513.zip from the browser.

**-------------------------------------------------**

Now, I am trying download multiple .zip files. **it causes issues**

 
**There is my 2nd rest service : The main problem**

```
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response downloadZippedFile() {
    ArrayList<String> PdfInputListFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111513.zip");
    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111514.zip");
    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111515.zip");


    // to print every file in every PdfInputListFiles 
    for (String myFile : PdfInputListFiles) {

        File file = new File(myFile);
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyJerseyZipFile.zip\"");
        return responseBuilder.build();

    }
    return null;
}
```

**Résult ==>** I can ONLY download the first file 201707111513.zip.

And it's normale cause of the return responseBuilder.build() line in the end of For loop.

**-------------------------------------------------**

Now, I am tryin this :

```
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response downloadZippedFile() {
    ArrayList<String> PdfInputListFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111513.zip");
    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111514.zip");
    PdfInputListFiles.add("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/201707111515.zip");


    // to print every file in every PdfInputListFiles 
    for (String myFile : PdfInputListFiles) {

        getFile(myFile);

    }
    return null;
}

public Response getFile(String str) {
    // Response response = null;
    File file = new File(str);
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyJerseyZipFile.zip\"");
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

**Résult ==>** No download is happen, I can't understand why calling getFile method doesn't return any downloaded file.

**
I need to download evry file in my list, in other words I have multiple paths and I need to download all those files.

SomeOne can help, or suggest an alternative solution ! 

Thank you

Comment: (1) your for loop doesn't loop due to the inner return statement. (2) You explicitly return null. (Generally) you cannot return multiple zip files in a single call. You must have your caller make a call for each one. I mean this in a positive way, but from your code snippets I think you need to work a bit on your core java.

Comment: Thank you Andry, you mean I should call my service (ex : http://localhost:8080/download) for each zip file ?!

Comment: @AndyBrown that's what you mean ?